# Emails to a specific address are bounced

Tags: email, spam-prevention, blacklist, email-bounces

I have been having issues with my emails to a particular client being bounced.  I sent two emails today - the same email to two mail addresses in the clients .com domain.  The first was sent to `fred@somewhere.com` and was bounced. The second was sent to `freds@somewhere.com` and (so far anyway) shows no signs of being bounced.

The bounce message I am getting is:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  fred@somewhere.com
    host in.hes.trendmicro.com [54.219.191.1]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<fred@somewhere.com>:
    550 5.7.1 <fred@somewhere.com>: Recipient address rejected:
    ERS-RBL.

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;fred@somewhere.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; in.hes.trendmicro.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 <fred@somewhere.com>: Recipient address rejected: ERS-RBL.
```

Now, that bounce message suggests that it is rejecting my *client's email address*, but when I look up error 550 5.7.1 it seems to suggest the fault is with *my SMTP server* being on a blacklist.

I've looked up both on blacklists and they come up clean.

Is it possible that a single email address - and not a whole domain - has been blacklisted? Where would I look this up?

Comment: Apparently (if you haven't checked it already), "ERS" is a custom blacklist maintained by TrendMicro. The interface for IP lookups is here - - https://ers.trendmicro.com/. Regarding individual emails, they can certainly be blocked but (so far as I am aware) blacklists don't generally dig down this deep (it's likely a fruitless task for spam prevention).

Comment: Yup, I did that and they are clean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a TrendMicro blacklist sort of deal. They have detected spam coming from that IP at some point and have decided to blacklist it. You can go here to check: https://www.ers.trendmicro.com/reputations

If it's in error, either get a new IP or request they remove it from their blacklist.